# Ensure GUI isn't locked up by incoming messages

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have a `UserControl` that was built following the MVVM pattern with an exposed function for other apps to send "commands" for the control to do. The commands in this case are `strings`. I'm trying to find a way to stop the GUI from hanging when a lot of commands are being sent in a short period. Each command should wait for the last one to finish.

Most of these commands do work on a 3rd party map control that is displayed in the main control's view.

The flow goes like this:

1. App sends command string to control.
2. Control calls a parse function to parse the string.
3. After parsing is complete, a certain class is called depending on the command.
4. Stuff happens i.e. create a model, update `ObservableCollection`, update the map control, etc.

Here's an example:

The usercontrol:

```
///The code behind for the control
public partial class MainControl : UserControl
{
    public MainControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Other apps call this function
    public void ExecuteCommand(string command)
    {
        CommandParser.StartParse(command);
    }
}
```

Class to parse the commands:

```
//Handles parsing a string command and calling the right class
public static class CommandParser
{
    public static void StartParse(string command)
    {
        //parses the command into a string array to hold different parts
        DoCommand(parsedCommand);
    }  

    private static void DoCommand(string[] command)
    {
        switch(command[0])
        {
            case "addpoint":
                AddCommand.AddObj(command);
                break;
            case "createstyle":
                CreateCommand.CreateObj(command);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Two classes that take the parsed command and do something:

```
//Adds objects to the third party map control
public static class AddCommand
{
    public static void AddObj(string[] command)
    {
        //Adds a point to the third party map control
        MapControl.AddPoint(new Point(90, -90)); //just an example
    }
}

//Creates model objects to add to observablecollections in viewmodels
public static class CreateCommand
{
    public static void CreateObj(string[] command)
    {
        //create a model
        //get the correct viewmodel
        viewModel.StylesCollection.Add(styleModel); //StylesCollection is an ObservableCollection
    }
}
```

Very basic example but should show the flow of everything. So imagine getting a a few thousands commands; Creating a model is fast, but because the map control (which is part of the GUI) is being updated every time, or an `ObservableCollection` (that has a control's itemsource bound to it) is being modified, the GUI hangs when receiving and doing all these commands.

Comment: The only reasonable way to solve this is to pass the messages through a queue. The control should read and process all currently available messages at regular intervals (and hence at its own pace).

Comment: Hmm good call, using a queue seems like a good option.

Comment: And most import, process all queued message *at once* without intermediate UI updates.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by intermediate UI updates? At the end of every processed command message, it usually performs an update on a UI control. Are you saying I should halt those updates until the last of the queued messages is processed?

Comment: If that's possible at all. At least try to do as few updates as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In (the probably unlikely) case that there is a considerable amount of work that can be done off the UI thread, you may implement multi threading. A very basic way of doing this would be as so.

First, create a new thread to run:

```
var task = new Thread(YourTask);
task.Start();
```

Then in the thread method where the calculations are done, delegate the result to the UI thread by calling `Dispatcher.Invoke`. Make sure you don't call Invoke too often (e.g. not more than 10 times per second), as this will again block the UI thread.

```
public void YourTask()
{
    // do calculations and get results

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
        new Action(() =>
        {
            // update the UI
        }));
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense, since calling `Dispatcher.Invoke` too often would still block the UI. Multithreading won't help in any way.

Comment: Not necessarily. Updating the UI in WPF extremely often (like multiple times a second) in general will result in the UI freezing, but multi threading is a simple solution to frequently updating your UI and ensures that the calculations are not completed on the same thread as your main thread.

Comment: Not at all if you still Invoke 100 times per second.

Comment: Don't disagree with you--given that I just said the same exact thing.

Comment: Assume that there is no calculation at all that can be offloaded to another thread. There is just a large amount of messages to receive which all result in direct UI updates. Multithreading will not help at all in such a scenario. Just saying "*you should implement multi threading*" is entirely pointless.